# Simplifying $\frac{8-i}{2+3i}$ to standard form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am just learning about "imaginary" numbers and having trouble understanding it all.

I'm supposed to write the following complex number in standard form.

$$\frac{8-i}{2+3i}$$

How can I start?

Comment: In general $\dfrac{a+bi}{x+yi} = \dfrac{a+bi}{x+yi}\times\dfrac{x-yi}{x-yi} = \dfrac{(a+bi)(x-yi)}{(x+yi)(x-yi)} = \dfrac{(ax+by)-(ay-bx)i}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: still need help with this problem. I took 8-i/2+3i and FOILed it I got 19-26i/13 but still need help. What do I do next and Have I done it right so far?

Comment: Multiply by $\dfrac{\overline{2+3i}}{\overline{2+3i}}$, which is $\dfrac{2-3i}{2-3i}$.

Comment: Do you mean I multiply 19-26i/13 by 2+3i/2+3i? and why do I do that? Could you explain?

Comment: $\dfrac{8-i}{2+3i}\!\times\!\dfrac{2-3i}{2-3i} = \dfrac{(8-i)(2-3i)}{(2+3i)(2-3i)} = \dfrac{8\!\times\!2+(-1)\!\times\!(-2)+8\!\times\!(-3)i+(-1)\!\times\!2i}{2^2+ 3^{2}} = \dfrac{19-26i}{13}$ So it seems you've done correct. I don't know anything about FOIL though...

Answer (score 3):

Use the complex conjugation:
$$\frac{8-i}{2+3i} = \frac{(8-i)(2-3i)}{(2+3i)(2-3i)} = \dots$$

Comment: I'm not sure if what I did was right or even where to start really, could you walk me through the problem step by step?  -13/4-9i? I'm literally JUST starting, new, GREEN!

Comment: Karen: how do you expand $(a +b)(a-b)$? (Denominator). How do you expand $(a-b)(c-d)$? It's the same procedure with factors of the form $a \pm bi$. Just remember that $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: Distribute???  I think

Comment: Yes! Some know the procedure as FOIL. But indeed, it all amounts to distributing.

Comment: ok, if I did this FOILing correctly...I got 19-26i/13? but I don't think that's the final step/answer is it?

Comment: $(19-26i)/13= 19/13 - 2i$ is the answer.